# Sequelize Store Queried value globally

Tags: node.js, express, sequelize.js

I am trying to figure out a way to store an object that was queried successfully with a global variable so I don't have to query the same model every time I want to access and use values from that query. I basically keep running into issues where I try to pass values of properties associated with my `organization` object, but I constantly get `undefined` when I try to use the object in instances when a query to the model is not present. Any suggestions?

appRoutes (`/sign-up/organization` POST captures `organization`, but `/settings/add-user` POST comes up with `undefined`:

```
 var express = require('express');
    var appRoutes   = express.Router();
    var passport = require('passport');
    var localStrategy = require('passport-local').Strategy;
    var models = require('../models/db-index');

appRoutes.route('/settings/add-users')

            .get(function(req, res){
                models.Organization.find({
                    where: {
                        organizationId: req.user.organizationId
                    }, attributes: ['organizationName','admin','members']
                }).then(function(organization){
                    res.render('pages/app/add-users.hbs',{
                        user: req.user,
                        organization: organization
                    });
                })
            })

            .post(function(req, res, organization){
                console.log('Initiated POST Method');

                models.Member.create({

                    organizationId: req.organization.organizationId,
                    memberEmail: req.body.addMember,

                }).then(function(){
                    console.log("Success");
                    res.redirect('/app/settings/add-users');
                })

            });

    appRoutes.route('/sign-up/organization')

        .get(function(req, res){
            models.User.find({
                where: {
                    user_id: req.user.email
                }, attributes: [ 'user_id', 'email'
                ]
            }).then(function(user){
                res.render('pages/app/sign-up-organization.hbs',{
                    user: req.user
                });
            })  
        })

        .post(function(req, res, user){
            models.Organization.create({
                organizationName: req.body.organizationName,
                admin: req.body.admin
            }).then(function(organization, user){

                models.Member.create({
                    organizationId: organization.organizationId,
                    memberEmail: req.user.email,
                    userId: req.user.user_id
                },{ where: { user_id: req.user.user_id }});
                res.redirect('/app');
            }).catch(function(error){
                res.send(error);
                console.log('Error at Post' + error);
            })
        });


    module.exports = appRoutes;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem seems to be twofold.

First, this line:

```
.post(function(req, res, organization){
```

This will not work, the method signature for express post requests doesn't pass data in like that. Express uses middleware and in every case the organization argument would be either undefined or a function that is called to go to the next middleware in the stack.

Now, here:

```
res.render('pages/app/add-users.hbs',{
    user: req.user,
    organization: organization
});
```

This is the correct way to send the organization data into the view. But you then must store the data in your html so it gets passed into the post request.

This is done by putting the data in an input inside the form that is then posted to the post method.
For example, if the organization object has say, an ID and a name. Looks something like this:

```
{
    organizationId: 'SomeID',
    Name: 'Organization Name'
}
```

then for the data to persist you must have this in your html:

```
<form action="/settings/add-users" method="post">
    <input type="hidden" name="organization.organizationId" value="SomeId" />
    <input type="hidden" name="organization.Name" value="Organization Name" />
    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Now in your post method you would retrieve the data like this:

```
            .post(function(req, res, organization){
                console.log('Initiated POST Method');
                console.log(req.body.organization.organizationId);
                console.log(req.body.organization.Name);
                models.Member.create({
                    organizationId: req.body.organization.organizationId,
                    memberEmail: req.body.addMember,

                }).then(function(){
                    console.log("Success");
                    res.redirect('/app/settings/add-users');
                })

            });
```

Note: for all of this to work you must use the body-parser middleware for express with urlencoded extended set to true.

```
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }))
```